# how can edit row when datagridview is databound

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

i have datagridview is bindingsurce table of database

datagridview load data from database

i wanna after get data from database edit row in datagredview using textboxs

i am using this code for Edit data

```
private void btn_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
   DataGridViewRow dr = dgvadministration.Rows[index_Row];

   dr.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Masseurs_Code.Text);
   dr.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Session_Type_Code.Text);
   dr.Cells[6].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_C_Order_Masseurs.Text);
   dr.Cells[7].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt_Room_No.Text);
   dr.Cells[8].Value = dtp_Session_Date.Text;
   dr.Cells[9].Value = cbx_Session_done.Checked == true ? true : false;
   dr.Cells[10].Value = txt_Session_Note.Text;
}
```

and get `index_Row` from `dgvadministration_CellClick`

```
 private int index_Row;
        private void dgvadministration_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Clear_Session_Data();
                index_Row = e.RowIndex;
                session_Code_Serial = Convert.ToInt32(dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                txt_Masseurs_Code.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value?.ToString();
                txt_Masseurs_Name.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value?.ToString();
                txt_Session_Type_Code.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value?.ToString();
                txt_Session_Type_Name.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value?.ToString();
                txt_C_Order_Masseurs.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value?.ToString();
                txt_Room_No.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value?.ToString();
                if (dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value != null)
                {
                    DateTime CoStartDate = (DateTime)dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value;
                    dtp_Session_Date.Text = CoStartDate.ToShortDateString();
                }

                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk_Session_Done = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

                if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk_Session_Done.Value) == true)
                {
                    cbx_Session_done.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cbx_Session_done.Checked = false;
                }
                txt_Session_Note.Text = dgvadministration.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value?.ToString();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

but `dr.Cells[2].Value` is null and al dr.Cells[X].Value
despite of `Convert.ToInt32(txt_Masseurs_Code.Text);`  is not null and other textbox

***Note*** before load data from database this code edit row is working when add Rows programmability using this code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Session_Code");
            DataRow dr = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Session_Code"] = i.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            dgvadministration.DataSource = dt;
```

Why is this happening, and how do I Edit this Row ????

Comment: Well, for starters, where is `index_Row` coming from? Are you sure `dr` actually contains values after the line of code … `DataGridViewRow dr = dgvadministration.Rows[index_Row];` executes? Does the grid have a `DataSource` when the `btn_Edit_Click` event fires?

Comment: index_Row` coming from event `dgvadministration_CellClick` i'm update question

yes `DataGridViewRow dr = dgvadministration.Rows[index_Row];` executes when click  `btn_Edit_Click` 

but `dr` is null despite of textboxs is not null

Comment: this code is work fine before load data from database to datagridview 
but after load data `dr` always null

Comment: I am pretty sure the rows “Cells” values may be `null` but `dr` is not `null.` I assume this because… IF `index_Row` was an “invalid” row index, then you would get an index out of bounds exception. Since it appears this is not happening, then we can pretty much guarantee that `dr` IS a valid row in the grid. However, the “Cells” in that row may be `null.` This is what I do not follow with your comment… _”but dr.Cells[2].Value is null”_ ? This should make NO difference.

Comment: Since the code is “assigning” values to those `null` cells, then that should not be a problem. So, I am not sure what the problem would be here. I would be curious as to “why” are the cells `null` to begin with. In other words, whatever row `index_Row` points to in the grid… what cells in that row are `null` and “why” are they null?

Comment: It could be, that `index_Row` points to the grids “new” row, in which case all the cells WOULD be `null.` If this is the case AND the grid is data bound, then you may have a problem here because you CAN programmatically “edit” those cells, however the cells will not be saved to the grids underlying data source as a “new” row.

Comment: IF a `DataGridView` is data bound, THEN, you CAN programmatically “edit” existing cells in the grid, however you CAN NOT programmatically “add” new rows directly to the GRID. You have to programmatically add the new row to the grids data source not the grid.

Comment: Also, depending on the data source in the grid, the “user” CAN “add” new rows directly into the grid. That is the purpose of the grids “new” blank row at the bottom of the grid. This is where the posted code should work UNLESS `index_Row` points to the grids “new” row. In this case, is what will happen, is that when the user clicks on the “edit” button, and the cells in the grids “new” row are filled with the values from the text boxes. This will display as expected, however, as soon as the user clicks on a cell in the new row… the values will be cleared.

Comment: I am guessing something like this may be going on. In other words, the posted code will work when “editing” existing cells, however it will not allow the user to “add” a new row by clicking on the grids new row, then fill the text boxes then click the “edit” button. If the user is allowed to add new rows, then your code is going to have to do something different. Can you clarify if adding a new row is intended in the posted code?